# ASP.NET/C# How Do I Display a PNG on a PDF

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I'm trying to use the following code to display a PNG file on a PDF.  I dropped the PNG into the same directory as the code to rule out any issues with incorrect directory paths, but all I'm getting is a little square on the PDF where the PNG should be located.  I'm using NReco.PDFGenerator to create the PDF.  Below are the relevant parts of the code:

Storing the PDF into an html table...

```
protected void expPDF_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

    div = BuildHTMLTable();

    export dmc = new export();

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    div.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));
    string s = sb.ToString();

    dmc.exportPDF("JCPS Collegiate Transcript", "Portrait", s);
}

protected HtmlGenericControl BuildHTMLTable()
{
    //Inner Div
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

    HtmlGenericControl divHeader = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

    //HeaderLabel 
    Table t = new Table();
    t.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    tr.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
    tr.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    tr.Font.Name = "Calibri";

    //JCPS Logo
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    Image img = new Image();
    img.ImageUrl = "JCPS Logo.png";
    tc.Controls.Add(img);
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);

    t.Rows.Add(tr);
    divHeader.Controls.Add(t);
    div.Controls.Add(divHeader);
    return div;
}
```

The function that builds and pushes out the PDF:

```
public void exportPDF(string fileName, string Orientation, string html)
{
    HtmlToPdfConverter pdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    html = html.Replace("\n", "");
    html = html.Replace("\t", "");
    html = html.Replace("\r", "");
    html = html.Replace("\"", "'");

    switch (Orientation)
    {
        case "Portrait":
            pdf.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
            break;
        case "Landscape":
            pdf.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            break;
        default:
            pdf.Orientation = PageOrientation.Default;
            break;
    }

    //In case needed for future
    //pdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--margin-top 35 --header-spacing 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0";

    pdf.Margins = new PageMargins { Top = 5, Bottom = 5, Left = 5, Right = 5 };
    pdf.PageFooterHtml = createPDFFooter();

    var pdfBytes = pdf.GeneratePdf(createPDFScript() + html + "</body></html>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}

private string createPDFScript()
{
    return "<html><head><style>td,th{line-height:20px;} tr { page-break-inside: avoid }</style><script>function subst() {var vars={};var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}" +
    "var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];for(var i in x) {var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);" +
    "for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];}}</script></head><body onload=\"subst()\">";
}

private string createPDFFooter()
{
    return "<div><table style='font-family:Tahoma; font-size:9px; width:100%'><tr><td style='text-align:left'>Research Dept|DD:FC:jpg</td><td style='text-align:right'>Page <span class=\"page\"></span> of <span class=\"topage\"></span></td></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, hope this helps others. Instead of using the Image class I discovered the HtmlImage class, and turns out it's quite simple. The only caveat is that it appears you have to use absolute paths to the image you are trying to collect - not a big deal but it was a little trial and error until I figured that out.

```
//JCPS Logo
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
HtmlImage studPic = new HtmlImage();
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
    studPic.Src = "/Dev/Data Management Center/Images/JCPS Logo.png";
else
    studPic.Src = "/Website/DMC/Images/JCPS Logo.png";
studPic.Height = 125;
studPic.Width = 150;
tc.Controls.Add(studPic);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
```